# Parse JSON arrays using OPENJSON to table

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql, open-json

I am confused how to shred my JSON data into a table because is not formatted with names for the arrays

The actual JSON file is much bigger (19K lines) so I only pulled a small portion of it out (the first two of top level and a few from within those.

```
DECLARE @txt1 varchar(max) = '{ "Rv0005": { "p.Glu540Asp": { "annotations": [ { "type": "drug", "drug": "moxifloxacin", "literature": "10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11", "confers": "resistance" } ], "genome_positions": [ 6857, 6858, 6859 ] }, "p.Ala504Thr": { "annotations": [ { "type": "drug", "drug": "ciprofloxacin", "confers": "resistance" }, { "type": "drug", "drug": "fluoroquinolones", "confers": "resistance" }, { "type": "drug", "drug": "levofloxacin", "confers": "resistance" }, { "type": "drug", "drug": "moxifloxacin", "confers": "resistance" }, { "type": "drug", "drug": "ofloxacin", "confers": "resistance" } ], "genome_positions": [ 6749, 6750, 6751 ] }, "p.Ala504Val": { "annotations": [ { "type": "drug", "drug": "ciprofloxacin", "confers": "resistance" }, { "type": "drug", "drug": "fluoroquinolones", "confers": "resistance" }, { "type": "drug", "drug": "levofloxacin", "confers": "resistance" }, { "type": "drug", "drug": "moxifloxacin", "confers": "resistance" }, { "type": "drug", "drug": "ofloxacin", "confers": "resistance" } ], "genome_positions": [ 6749, 6750, 6751 ] } }, "Rv2043c": { "p.Thr100Ile": { "annotations": [ { "type": "drug", "drug": "pyrazinamide", "literature": "10.1128/JCM.01214-17", "confers": "resistance" } ], "genome_positions": [ 2288942, 2288943, 2288944 ] }, "p.Thr160Ala": { "annotations": [ { "type": "drug", "drug": "pyrazinamide", "literature": "10.1128/JCM.01214-17", "confers": "resistance" } ], "genome_positions": [ 2288762, 2288763, 2288764 ] }, "c.101_102insT": { "annotations": [ { "type": "drug", "drug": "pyrazinamide", "confers": "resistance" } ], "genome_positions": [ 2289140, 2289141 ] } } }'

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@txt1)
```

The top level is a gene and this is just the data from two genes (Rv0005 = gene 1, Rv2043c = gene 2).  Each gene can have multiple mutations (e.g. Rv0005 has a mutation at p.Glu540Asp and p.Ala504Thr) and each of those mutations have some data associated with it (literature, resistance, genomic positions, etc.). I know I can parse portions of the JSON and JSON array out via

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@txt1) 
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@txt1, '$.Rv0005."p.Glu540Asp".genome_positions')
```

But I don't know how to shred the whole thing out without knowing what the keys/values are. In particular there are 35 unique genes (the top of the JSON tree) and each of the mutations are named under them but are unique (e.g. p.Glu540Asp, etc).

Ultimately I'd either like to pull the data into multiple normalized tables but honestly one big table would be fine like this

```
CREATE TABLE #Muts (gene varchar(max), mutations varchar(max), annotation_type varchar(max), annotation_drug varchar(max), annotation_literature varchar(max), annotation_confers  varchar(max), genome_positions int )
```

and the data for the first couple of values would look like this (notice that some mutations confer resistance to multiple drugs)

| gene | mutations | annotation_type | annotation_drug | annotation_literature | annotation_confers | genome_positions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rv0005 | p.Glu540Asp | drug | moxifloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6857 |
| Rv0005 | p.Glu540Asp | drug | moxifloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6858 |
| Rv0005 | p.Glu540Asp | drug | moxifloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6859 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | ciprofloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6849 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | fluoroquinolones | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6849 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | levofloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6849 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | moxifloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6849 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | ofloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6849 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | ciprofloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6850 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | fluoroquinolones | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6850 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | levofloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6850 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | moxifloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6850 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | ofloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6850 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | ciprofloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6851 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | fluoroquinolones | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6851 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | levofloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6851 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | moxifloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6851 |
| Rv0005 | p.Ala504Thr | drug | ofloxacin | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance | 6851 |

Comment: `varchar(max)` seems excessive, is the drug name likely to be 2 billion characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use CROSS APPLY with OPENJSON when you want to "pivot" a JSON array to a tabular table.

The following query return the expected result:

```
SELECT a.[key] as gene, b.[key] as mutations, c.*, d.value as genome_positions
FROM OPENJSON(@txt1) a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.value) b
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(b.value,'$.annotations')
WITH ( 
    annotation_type nvarchar(100) '$.type'
    , annotation_drug nvarchar(100) '$.drug'
    , annotation_literature nvarchar(100) '$.literature'
    , annotation_confers nvarchar(100) '$.confers'
) c
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(b.value,'$.genome_positions') d
```

Result:

[image]

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=92182499f6ec4ae4ac1a54ff9eb51c2e)

Comment: I think that is close but it needs the genome_positions which is the same level as annotations

Comment: I added it with an edit. Do not hesitate to validate the answer :)

Comment: @user918967 This is the correct answer. Note that you don't need the JPaths on the properties if they are the same name

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'{
    "Rv0005": {
        "p.Glu540Asp": {
            "annotations": [
                {
                    "type": "drug",
                    "drug": "moxifloxacin",
                    "literature": "10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11",
                    "confers": "resistance"
                }
            ],
            "genome_positions": [
                6857,
                6858,
                6859
            ]
        },
        "p.Ala504Thr": {
            "annotations": [
                {
                    "type": "drug",
                    "drug": "ciprofloxacin",
                    "confers": "resistance"
                },
                {
                    "type": "drug",
                    "drug": "fluoroquinolones",
                    "confers": "resistance"
                },
                {
                    "type": "drug",
                    "drug": "levofloxacin",
                    "confers": "resistance"
                },
                {
                    "type": "drug",
                    "drug": "moxifloxacin",
                    "confers": "resistance"
                },
                {
                    "type": "drug",
                    "drug": "ofloxacin",
                    "confers": "resistance"
                }
            ],
            "genome_positions": [
                6749,
                6750,
                6751
            ]
        },
        "p.Ala504Val": {
            "annotations": [
                {
                    "type": "drug",
                    "drug": "ciprofloxacin",
                    "confers": "resistance"
                },
                {
                    "type": "drug",
                    "drug": "fluoroquinolones",
                    "confers": "resistance"
                },
                {
                    "type": "drug",
                    "drug": "levofloxacin",
                    "confers": "resistance"
                },
                {
                    "type": "drug",
                    "drug": "moxifloxacin",
                    "confers": "resistance"
                },
                {
                    "type": "drug",
                    "drug": "ofloxacin",
                    "confers": "resistance"
                }
            ],
            "genome_positions": [
                6749,
                6750,
                6751
            ]
        }
    },
    "Rv2043c": {
        "p.Thr100Ile": {
            "annotations": [
                {
                    "type": "drug",
                    "drug": "pyrazinamide",
                    "literature": "10.1128/JCM.01214-17",
                    "confers": "resistance"
                }
            ],
            "genome_positions": [
                2288942,
                2288943,
                2288944
            ]
        },
        "p.Thr160Ala": {
            "annotations": [
                {
                    "type": "drug",
                    "drug": "pyrazinamide",
                    "literature": "10.1128/JCM.01214-17",
                    "confers": "resistance"
                }
            ],
            "genome_positions": [
                2288762,
                2288763,
                2288764
            ]
        },
        "c.101_102insT": {
            "annotations": [
                {
                    "type": "drug",
                    "drug": "pyrazinamide",
                    "confers": "resistance"
                }
            ],
            "genome_positions": [
                2289140,
                2289141
            ]
        }
    }
}';

-- test if it is a legit JSON
SELECT ISJSON(@json) AS Result;

SELECT genes.[Key] AS gene
    , mutations.[Key] AS mutation
    , annotations.*
    , JSON_VALUE(mutations.value, '$.genome_positions[0]') as [gen_pos1]
    , JSON_VALUE(mutations.value, '$.genome_positions[1]') as [gen_pos2]
    , JSON_VALUE(mutations.value, '$.genome_positions[2]') as [gen_pos3]
FROM OPENJSON (@json) AS genes
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(genes.value) AS mutations
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(mutations.value, '$.annotations') 
WITH 
(
    [type] VARCHAR(20)              '$.type'
    , [drug] VARCHAR(20)            '$.drug'
    , [literature] VARCHAR(200)     '$.literature'
    , [confers] VARCHAR(20)         '$.confers'
) AS annotations
```

**Output**

```
+---------+---------------+------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
|  gene   |   mutation    | type |       drug       |                literature                 |  confers   | gen_pos1 | gen_pos2 | gen_pos3 |
+---------+---------------+------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Rv0005  | p.Glu540Asp   | drug | moxifloxacin     | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance |     6857 |     6858 | 6859     |
| Rv0005  | p.Ala504Thr   | drug | ciprofloxacin    | NULL                                      | resistance |     6749 |     6750 | 6751     |
| Rv0005  | p.Ala504Thr   | drug | fluoroquinolones | NULL                                      | resistance |     6749 |     6750 | 6751     |
| Rv0005  | p.Ala504Thr   | drug | levofloxacin     | NULL                                      | resistance |     6749 |     6750 | 6751     |
| Rv0005  | p.Ala504Thr   | drug | moxifloxacin     | NULL                                      | resistance |     6749 |     6750 | 6751     |
| Rv0005  | p.Ala504Thr   | drug | ofloxacin        | NULL                                      | resistance |     6749 |     6750 | 6751     |
| Rv0005  | p.Ala504Val   | drug | ciprofloxacin    | NULL                                      | resistance |     6749 |     6750 | 6751     |
| Rv0005  | p.Ala504Val   | drug | fluoroquinolones | NULL                                      | resistance |     6749 |     6750 | 6751     |
| Rv0005  | p.Ala504Val   | drug | levofloxacin     | NULL                                      | resistance |     6749 |     6750 | 6751     |
| Rv0005  | p.Ala504Val   | drug | moxifloxacin     | NULL                                      | resistance |     6749 |     6750 | 6751     |
| Rv0005  | p.Ala504Val   | drug | ofloxacin        | NULL                                      | resistance |     6749 |     6750 | 6751     |
| Rv2043c | p.Thr100Ile   | drug | pyrazinamide     | 10.1128/JCM.01214-17                      | resistance |  2288942 |  2288943 | 2288944  |
| Rv2043c | p.Thr160Ala   | drug | pyrazinamide     | 10.1128/JCM.01214-17                      | resistance |  2288762 |  2288763 | 2288764  |
| Rv2043c | c.101_102insT | drug | pyrazinamide     | NULL                                      | resistance |  2289140 |  2289141 | NULL     |
+---------+---------------+------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a temporary table will make it easier to pivot the data from the unfolded json.

> ```
> DECLARE @txt1 varchar(max) = '{...}'
>
> IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpJsonUnfolded', 'U') IS NOT NULL
> DROP TABLE #tmpJsonUnfolded;
>
> SELECT 
>   lvl1.[key] as gene
> , lvl2.[key] as mutations
> , lvl3.[key] as data_class
> , lvl4.[key] as num
> , lvl5.[key] as col
> , case 
>   when lvl3.[key] = 'genome_positions' 
>   then lvl4.[value]
>   when lvl3.[key] = 'annotations' 
>   then lvl5.[value]
>   end as [value] 
> --, lvl4.[value] as value4
> --, lvl5.[value] as value5
> INTO #tmpJsonUnfolded
> FROM OPENJSON(@txt1) lvl1
> CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(lvl1.value) lvl2
> CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(lvl2.value) lvl3
> CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(lvl3.value) lvl4
> OUTER APPLY (
>   SELECT *
>   FROM OPENJSON(lvl4.value) 
>   WHERE lvl3.[key] = 'annotations'
> ) lvl5;
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   gene
> , mutations
> , [type] as annotation_type
> , [num] as annotation_num
> , [drug] as annotation_drug
> , [literature] as annotation_literature
> , [confers] as annotation_confers
> , [genome_positions]
> from (
>   select 
>     gene
>   , mutations
>   , num
>   , [col] 
>   , [value] 
>   from #tmpJsonUnfolded
>   where data_class = 'annotations'
>   
>   union all
>   
>   select 
>     gene
>   , mutations
>   , 0
>   , data_class as [col] 
>   , string_agg([value], ', ') as [value] 
>   from #tmpJsonUnfolded
>   where data_class = 'genome_positions'
>   group by gene, mutations, data_class
> ) src
> pivot (
>   max([value])
>   for [col] in ([type], [drug], [literature], [confers], [genome_positions])
> ) pvt
> ```

> ```
> gene    | mutations     | annotation_type | annotation_num | annotation_drug  | annotation_literature                     | annotation_confers | genome_positions         
> :------ | :------------ | :-------------- | -------------: | :--------------- | :---------------------------------------- | :----------------- | :------------------------
> Rv0005  | p.Ala504Thr   | drug            |              0 | ciprofloxacin    | null                                      | resistance         | 6749, 6750, 6751         
> Rv0005  | p.Ala504Thr   | drug            |              1 | fluoroquinolones | null                                      | resistance         | null                     
> Rv0005  | p.Ala504Thr   | drug            |              2 | levofloxacin     | null                                      | resistance         | null                     
> Rv0005  | p.Ala504Thr   | drug            |              3 | moxifloxacin     | null                                      | resistance         | null                     
> Rv0005  | p.Ala504Thr   | drug            |              4 | ofloxacin        | null                                      | resistance         | null                     
> Rv0005  | p.Ala504Val   | drug            |              0 | ciprofloxacin    | null                                      | resistance         | 6749, 6750, 6751         
> Rv0005  | p.Ala504Val   | drug            |              1 | fluoroquinolones | null                                      | resistance         | null                     
> Rv0005  | p.Ala504Val   | drug            |              2 | levofloxacin     | null                                      | resistance         | null                     
> Rv0005  | p.Ala504Val   | drug            |              3 | moxifloxacin     | null                                      | resistance         | null                     
> Rv0005  | p.Ala504Val   | drug            |              4 | ofloxacin        | null                                      | resistance         | null                     
> Rv0005  | p.Glu540Asp   | drug            |              0 | moxifloxacin     | 10.1128/AAC.00825-17;10.1128/JCM.06860-11 | resistance         | 6857, 6858, 6859         
> Rv2043c | c.101_102insT | drug            |              0 | pyrazinamide     | null                                      | resistance         | 2289140, 2289141         
> Rv2043c | p.Thr100Ile   | drug            |              0 | pyrazinamide     | 10.1128/JCM.01214-17                      | resistance         | 2288942, 2288943, 2288944
> Rv2043c | p.Thr160Ala   | drug            |              0 | pyrazinamide     | 10.1128/JCM.01214-17                      | resistance         | 2288762, 2288763, 2288764
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3567f72f103a60d8d5b8e701fbc76172)*